# why does semantic-ui-react have circular dependencies, and how do you resolve that when using webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui-react in a create-react-app based React app. I ran into an issue where simply using components like `<CardGroup>` or `<StepGroup>` throws a generic, and unfortunately unhelpful, error message:
`ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization`

After banging my head against the wall for several hours, I finally figured out that there are circular dependencies in those components, with `<Card>` and `<Step>` respectively.

Then I stumbled upon [this old github issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3472), with [this interesting comment](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3472#issuecomment-469226098). I would love to understand two things here:

1. What aspect of the design makes this a difficult thing to resolve?
2. How can/should this work with webpack?